# DownloadData comes in which package of restfb?

Tags: download, package, restfb

I got some task regarding `restfb` and I am totally new to this subject.

I took one of the samples from search forums but there is no package given for `DownloadData`. I searched but couldn't find it.

I'd like to know: to which package `DownloadData` belongs to?

I want to know the whole package name to run my program.
Below is the sample code.

```
if (count >= userArr.length) 
{
    DownloadData dd = new DownloadData();
    dd.userIds = userArr;
    new Thread(dd).start();
    count = 0;

    if (arraySize < usersNumber) 
    {
        userArr = new String[arraySize];
    } else {
        userArr = new String[usersNumber];
    }
    usersNumber -= userArr.length;
}
```

I also want to know the content package.

```
for(User friend:myFriends.getData())
{
    Connection<Page> myMovies = facebookClient.fetchConnection(friend.getId() 
    + "/movies", Page.class);

    content = content + "Name: " + friend.getName();
    for(Page page:myMovies.getData())
    {
        content = content  + "\n" + "Movies: " + page.getName() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: DownloadData is not a standard Java package so you should ask the person who gave you that code to tell you where to get it.

Comment: maybe you can tell us what you like to do. `DownloadData` is not a part of RestFB.